# How to query the Cognito Group of a logged in user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am using AWS Amplify. I have a Cognito Auth with 2 groups. Using Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser, I can tell the email address of the logged-in user but is there a way to determine the group of the user?

Answer (score 0):

There are two alternative solutions: either establish Amplify Auth Admin Queries API (to use **listGroupsForUser** query) or use AWS SDK Cognito Identity Provider Client to use **AdminListGroupsForUserCommand**.

- [Enabling Admin Queries API](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/auth/admin/)
- [Using AWS SDK Cognito Identity Provider Client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cognito-identity-provider/classes/adminlistgroupsforusercommand.html)